# C# Generic Type Inheritance Question

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

```
class ThirdType : SecondType
{
}

class SecondType : FirstType<SecondType>
{
}

class FirstType<T> 
{
    public static void ShowType()
    {       
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}


ThirdType.ShowType();
```

In this code, it will print "SecondType"

I want to know if it is possible to print "ThirdType" here?

I need a way when I call the static method ThirdType.ShowType(), it will print out ThirdType. Two ways I can think of is to modify the method to

```
public static void ShowType<O>() 
{ 
  Console.WriteLine(typeof(O).Name);
}
```

another way is

```
public static void ShowType(Type t)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().Name);
}
```

I can't think of any other ways

Comment: There is absolutely no reason it should print ThirdType... it wouldn't make any sense

Comment: why do you need that? Whatever you're trying to do, I'm sure there must be a better way...

Comment: There are no other ways. As you are calling an inherited static method, there is no way for the method to know that you used `ThirdType.ShowType()` instead of `FirstType<SecondType>.ShowType()` to call it.

Comment: You can't get polymorphism for things that are static.

Comment: Thanks all, I think I am actually looking for some sort of GetMethodInvokerBaseType() method from .net. I guess it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

No. Why should it print `ThirdType`? You are printing the type of `T` which is the generic parameter you passed to `FirstType`. And this is `SecondType`: `FirstType<SecondType>` 
If you want to print `ThirdType` you need to change your method to this:

```
public void ShowType()
{       
    Console.WriteLine(GetType().Name);
}
```

and call it from an instance of the class:

```
ThirdType tt = new ThirdType();
tt.ShowType();
```

Comment: However, `GetType` is not a static method, so you can't use it here. You have to create an instance of the class to use the `GetType` method.

Comment: @Guffa and @Anton: Please read my answer again. I explicitly state that you need to create an instance. Also please note that `ShowType` isn't static any more...

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: It didn't when I wrote the comment.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I can only comment on the answer as it looks at the time, I can not see future changes to it... ;)

Comment: This is definitely a solution but my real problem is the method is static, Its not possible for me to change it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your ThirdType like this:

```
class ThirdType : FirstType<ThirdType>
{
}
```

or

```
class ThirdType : SecondType<ThirdType>
{
}

class SecondType<T> : FirstType<T>
{
}
```

In this case it would print "ThirdType". But I thinks this would be bad practice, the best solution I can see is described in **Daniel**'s answer

Answer (score 0):

As You have written in you code

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
```

and T here is "`SecondType`" which you passed in second class inheriatance .

thants y its printing "SecondType"

Modify you code something like this : may work for you

```
class ThirdType : SecondType<ThirdType>
{
}

class SecondType<T> : FirstType<T>
{
}

class FirstType<T> 
{
    public static void ShowType<T>()
    {       
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

ThirdType.ShowType();

Comment: I know, just for example. I really need a way for the caller to know its type.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it to throw the generics out the window, and replace the line

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name);
```

`this.GetType()` will return the actual type of the object, in this case `ThirdType`.

And remove `static`from the method. At least if you want to make sure this makes any sense.

Comment: @Chia - But why do you need it to be a static method? Then the method is not inherited, and always "belong" to ThirdType. Your example does not work either, since you can't call ThirdType.ShowType(). Only FirstType.ShowType(). And when static, the only way to get this method to return what you want is to write the following to the console `typeof(ThirdType).Name`, or simply "ThirdType". Quite useless of course, but nothing you can do here for a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add `Console.WriteLine("ThirdType")` ;-)

Just kidding - no it is not possible with your current object hierarchy because you are printing the type of the generic type argument (`<T>`) so the only way to have it print ThirdType is if ThirdType inherited from `FirstType<ThirdType>`.